# Best Practise: How to keep Angular interfaces and WebAPI classes together

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have classes in my .net core Web API (which are used in multiple actions).

I have typescript interfaces defined in my angular frontend application (of these classes).

What is the preferred way of adhering to DRY principles and "keeping these together" so I can share the models between multiple WebAPI/frotends?

Comment: Anyway you want.

Comment: This seems a fair question. Vote to close? How so?

Comment: Questions asking what is a "best practice" are just very broad and opinionated. There are many possible answers with no single answer being correct. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well yes. I am looking for opinions. This is a perfectly acceptable question.

Comment: I think the question is legit and will help other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a good way to keep the mixed code together. I would go with something like:

- Create a Nuget package for the c# classes
- Create an NPM package for the typescript interfaces
- Have a strict versioning policy to keep the two packages in sync

This way, you can utilize the native ecosystems for both your backend (Nuget) and frontend (NPM) without any custom hacks.

It will also allow you to consume just one of the two if some of your applications only need the frontend or backend models.

Answer (score 0):

you can create end points for this api and backend like with endpoints, my recommendation, other framework, lang, or lang, in angular you can create a service for this end points.